# maven-clean-plugin is not removing all given directories

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-clean-plugin

In my project `.pom` I set up the `maven-clean-plugin` like so:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <filesets>
      <fileset>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/bower_components</directory>
      </fileset>
      <fileset>
        <directory>node_modules</directory>
      </fileset>
      <fileset>
        <directory>node</directory>
      </fileset>
    </filesets>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

The plugin purpose is to remove directories which are created by `frontend-maven-plugin`. Anyway the last one works OK.

---

**Problem**

Now the issue is that for no reason, one of the above folders is never removed. And it is always the one "in the middle". I added 3 `filesets` and always the 2nd one is not removed, see logs:

```
[INFO] Deleting /src/main/webapp/bower_components (includes = [], excludes = [])
[INFO] Deleting /node_modules (includes = [.bindings], excludes = [])
[INFO] Deleting /node (includes = [], excludes = [])
```

If I change folders' order:

```
[INFO] Deleting /src/main/webapp/bower_components (includes = [], excludes = [])
[INFO] Deleting /node (includes = [.bindings], excludes = [])
[INFO] Deleting /node_modules (includes = [], excludes = [])
```

**And also the 2nd option always contains this part:** `includes = [.bindings]` which I believe results in the folder not being deleted.

Why is that happening, and how to fix it?

---

**EDIT, debug log**

`mvn -X clean` result, I think this is where it breaks:

http://pastebin.com/ep1i2Bjk

After parsing the `pom.xml` it reads the configuration with this parameter. **However, I did not put it there.**

Comment: run `mvn` command with `-X` option to see full logs.

Comment: @FranMontero see update

Comment: You have not defined what to include nor what's excluded...See the [example in the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html). BTW: Just try `mvn -D clean.verbose=true package` Apart from that the output shows all configuration parts inclusive those which are defaults for the plugin.

Comment: @khmarbaise because I want to remove the directory, not it's content. Why one folder is deleted OK and another is not?

Comment: Sorry...you wan't to remove a directory without removing it's content ? I assume i misunderstand a thing but from my point of view it does not make sense to try to delete a directory without removing it's content.

Comment: @khmarbaise You do not need to specify the content of the folder. Obviously, what is inside should be deleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>OK I have found the issue! It is actually a bug in the plugin and is already reported. It affects the `maven-clean-plugin 2.6.1`.</s>

It was my side misconfiguration, read on for the resolution.

**Situation**

You have a parent project and a child project, both have to use the plugin.

Now;

- in parent project you specify some filesets.
- in child project you specify some filesets.

---

**What I think is expected:**

Plugin read both parent's and child's filesets and cleans them all.

**What happens:**

Plugin OVERRIDES the parent's filesets with child's filesets. Filesets are overriden in order. HOWEVER the parents configuration for the fileset is not cleared!

---

My situation:
Parent .pom:

```
<filesets>
   <fileset>
      <directory>test-output</directory>
   </fileset>
   <fileset>
     <directory>${basedir}/</directory>
     <includes>
        <include>.bindings</include>
     </includes> 
   </fileset>
</filesets>
```

Childs pom:

```
<filesets>
    <fileset>
        <directory>node</directory>
    </fileset>
    <fileset>
        <directory>node_modules</directory>
    </fileset>
    <fileset>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/bower_components</directory>
    </fileset>
</filesets>
```

And with the above information; the config read by plugin is:

```
<filesets>
    <fileset>
        <directory>node</directory>
    </fileset>
    <fileset>
        <directory>node_modules</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>.bindings</include>
        </includes>
    </fileset>
    <fileset>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/bower_components</directory>
    </fileset>
</filesets>
```

instead of a config with 5 filesets.

Bug report https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCLEAN-64

### **RESOLVED**

> For configuration there are some magic attributes to instruct how xml elements should be combined. In this case add combine.children="append" to the filesets tag. More details about this can be found on the POM Reference page. http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Worth mentioning is that it is enough to set `combine.children="append"` in child's project `.pom`.

Comment: On the same note, I had an empty plugin definition on the parent. I deleted the `maven-clean-plugin` from the parent and my child clean worked.